# Prove: $\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x}=0$ has a real root between $\frac13a$ and $\frac23a$, and one between $-\frac23b$ and $-\frac13b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discriminant

> If $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, prove that the equation
>   $$\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x}=0$$
>   has two real roots; one between $\frac13a$ and $\frac23a$, and one between $-\frac23b$ and $-\frac13b$.

---

My attempt:

I simplified the given expression, applied the discriminant for two real roots and got stuck on this inequality: $4({a}^2 - {ab}+{b}^2)$$>$$0$

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: The equation is wrong, you should look at roots of $$\frac{1}{x-a} + \frac{1}{x\color{red}{+}b} + \frac1x = 0$$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

$$4(a^{2}- ab + b^{2}) = (2a-b)^{2} + 3b^{2}$$

---

I think question is wrong. For exmaple, if $a = 1, b = 2$, then two solutions are $1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and none of them lies between $-4/3$ and $-2/3$ since both are positive.

Comment: Thanks, and how do I proceed from here?

Comment: @PaulaM Since this is a sum of two squares, it should be nonnegative. Now it can't be 0 because $a, b$ are both positive.

Comment: This doesn't help with the part where you have to prove that the roots lie between the given points. It only proves the existence of two real roots.

Comment: Edited - question seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Hui is right the equation should be** $$ f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+b}+\frac{1}{x} =0 ~~~a,b >0. ~~~(1)$$
Then $$f(a/3)=\frac{9(a+b)}{2a(a+3b)}>0$$ and $$f(2a/3)=~-\frac{9b}{2a(2a+3b)}<0.$$ So by the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT) this equation (1) has one root in $(a/2,2a/3).$
Next, $$ f(-b/3)=~-\frac{9(a+b)}{2b(3a+b)}<0$$ and $$f(-2b/3)=\frac{9a}{2b(3a+2b)}>0.$$ So again by IVT, equation (1) has one root in $(-2b/3,-b/3).$

Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The defining equation is symmetric in $a$ and $b$; the ostensible root-bounding intervals are not. This, in and of itself, doesn't guarantee that the question is invalid, but it reasonably raises some suspicions. Be that as it may ...

---

Clearing fractions gives the quadratic
$$3 x^2 - 2 (a+b) x + a b = 0$$
which we can solve explicitly:
$$x = \frac13\left(\;a+b \pm \sqrt{a^2-a b+ b^2}\;\right)$$
Presumably, from the target root-bounding intervals, one of the roots "should be" positive, and one negative. The positive root must arise from taking "$\pm$" to be "$+$", so that we have 
$$\frac13a \leq \frac13\left(\;a+b + \sqrt{a^2-a b+ b^2}\;\right) \leq \frac23a \quad\to\quad 0 \leq b + \sqrt{a^2-a b+ b^2} \leq a \quad\to\quad b\leq a$$
This condition on $a$ and $b$ was not assumed, so the conclusion is not valid. (Likewise, having the negative root bounded by the $b$-terms introduces an additional condition.) $\square$